# The HTML search tool does not post the results

Tags: html, search, input

I understand the HTML code for a search engine is something like:

```
    <form id="searchbox" action="SearchResults.php" >
        <input type="search" id="search" name="search" required="true"
               placeholder="search for ..." />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
```

Here is the second file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>MCJTD: Search Results</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include("header.php"); ?>
        <section>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

I assume I need to tell it where to display the search results. What am I missing? The SearchResults.php page open but the search results are not displayed.

Comment: which method you have using for request data to server ?

Comment: search results for what exactly? and you realize that `<form>` without a (POST) method defaults to a GET.

Comment: I know this may sound a bit rude (which is not intended), but I hope you're not going to take as much time to respond (about comments left) as you did in your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/38215003/ - The longer you wait, the more time it takes for the people who are presently in here to give/offer you a solution. So, you either post your full code, or wait till later if/when other people visit your question. Good luck.

Comment: I just now added "method=post" and still no results.

Comment: I modified the SearchResults.php page to include and output tag, still no results. <output form="searchbox" name="results" for="search"></output>